# Show div using plugin cleditor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put on the form an image that shows and hides the div

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:hide_menu()" id="hidden"><img bla bla>
```

here are my function in javascript

```
function hide_menu(){

    if(document.getElementById('responder').style.display == "none"){

        document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = "block"
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#responder').position().top}, 'slow');
        document.getElementById('cleditor').focus();
        document.getElementById('cleditor').select();

    }else{
        document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = "none"
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#da-content-wrap').position().top}, 'slow');
    }
}
```

is working perfectly, the problem is a bug that happens when I show div

look this picture

![enter image description here][1]

The other problem is that not the focus to the field

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhcQe.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Try calling document.getElementById('cleditor').refresh() after it has been shown again.

Maybe like this:

```
function hide_menu(){

    if(document.getElementById('responder').style.display == "none"){

        document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = "block"

        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#responder').position().top}, 'slow', function() {
           document.getElementById('cleditor').refresh();
           document.getElementById('cleditor').focus();
           document.getElementById('cleditor').select();
        });

    }else{
        document.getElementById('responder').style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById('button').style.display = "none"
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('#da-content-wrap').position().top}, 'slow');
    }
}
```

> .refresh() - Forces the editor to resize it's toolbar, textarea and iframe. This method should be called after initializing a hidden editor and making it visible, or after changing the the width, height or parent of the $main div element.

Comment: I changed my answer slightly, I have put the cleditor code inside the animation complete function. See if this works.